# Ruby Hash Dump Function Meaning?

Tags: ruby, dump

Learn Ruby the hard way has a study drill that involves hash's and  coding a dump function 
similar to the list function that we wrote a bit earlier in the book

The list function

```
def Dict.list(aDict)
#Prints out what's in the Dict
 aDict.each do |bucket|
  if bucket
    bucket.each {|k,v| puts k, v}
   end 
  end
 end
end
```

My problem is that i don't know what does mean  to dump should i delete all the key value pairs in the hash or do something else.We have a delete function

```
def Dict.delete(aDict , key )
 #Deletes the given key from the Dict
(0...bucket.lenght).each do |i|
 k,v = bucket[i]
 if key == k 
  bucket.delete_at(i)
  break 
  end 
 end
end
```

So im guessing dump is something else

Thanks in Advance

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

A bit of web searching for terms like "define dump computing" will put you on the right track, for example, [*The Free Dictionary* entry for "dump" says](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dump):

> **dump**, *v.tr.*
>
> **5.** *Computers* To transfer (data stored internally in a computer) from one place to another, as from a memory to a printout, without processing.

In your case it seems to mean to transfer the contents of the dictionary from the memory of the computer to the screen.

See also Ruby's builtin [`Marshal.dump(...)` function](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) for comparison.